# Spring cloud config server using multi repository but client could not read

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

Recently, I build a spring cloud config server for company business, the config server configuration like flw:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      label: master
      server:
        git:
          uri: http://gitlab.ugirls.com:9999/commonconfig.git
          search-paths: db,redis

          force-pull: true
          default-label: master
          repos:
              project1:
                    pattern: project1-*
                    cloneOnStart: true
                    uri: http://gitlab.ugirls.com:9999/project1.git

              project2: 
                    pattern: project2-*
                    cloneOnStart: true
                    uri: http://gitlab.ugirls.com:9999/project2.git
```

as my project has some common configuration file, so I put it to commonconfig.git.

commonconfig.git 
contains datasource-dev.properties, datasource-prod.properties

project1.git
contains application-dev.yml, application-prod.yml

up till now, it looks like ok, visit http://localhost:8411/project1-application.xml that's ok

```
{
name: "project1-application",
profiles: [
"dev"
],
label: "master",
version: "978c1dc67a6bb6672b7e7ae7620f2c5794897a31",
state: null,
propertySources: [
{
name: "http://gitlab.ugirls.com:9999/project1.git/application-dev.yml",
}...
```

and visit http://localhost:8411/datasource/dev still ok.

But....
my config client project: the bootstrap.yml like as flows:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: project1-application
  cloud:
    config:
      label: master
      profile: ${spring.profiles.active}
      uri: http://localhost:8411/
      name: project1-application,datasource
```

it only read application-dev.yml but not datasource.properties 
the log like this:

```
Located environment: name=project1-application, profiles=[dev], label=master, version=978c1dc67a6bb6672b7e7ae7620f2c5794897a31, state=null
2018-01-26 13:54:26.613  INFO [datasource,redis_chat,redis_main,redis_rank,,,] 6064 --- [           main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: CompositePropertySource [name='configService', propertySources=[MapPropertySource {name='configClient'}, MapPropertySource {name='http://gitlab.ugirls.com:9999/project1.git/application-dev.yml'}, MapPropertySource {name='http://gitlab.ugirls.com:9999/project1.git/application.yml'}]]
```

Once I changed 
spring.cloud.config.name=datasource

it will be only load datasource-dev.properties

could any one can explain it, or give me some advice? thanks

Comment: Config server can only read from one git repo at a time.

Comment: thanks, that means my config client only read one git repo at a time, either  http://gitlab.ugirls.com:9999/commonconfig.git or http://gitlab.ugirls.com:9999/project1.git ?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Ok, very thanks, finally, In spite of this limitation look like inflexible, I could only move common config files to each repository.

Answer (score 0):

Spring cloud config server now supports a "composite repo" setup that would allow you to add your repo that contains shared properties.

See the documentation [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#composite-environment-repositories).

For you, this would be something like:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: composite
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        composite:
        -
          type: git
          # Default URI is required to be present, even if not used
          uri: blahblah

          repos:
              project1:
                    pattern: project1-*
                    cloneOnStart: true
                    uri: http://gitlab.ugirls.com:9999/project1.git

              project2: 
                    pattern: project2-*
                    cloneOnStart: true
                    uri: http://gitlab.ugirls.com:9999/project2.git
        -
          type: git
          uri: http://gitlab.ugirls.com:9999/commonconfig.git
          search-paths: db,redis
```

Comment: @user1685190 I know you asked this over 2 years ago, so you might not be intesreted. But in case you are, know that I am unsure if cloneOnStart works under composite repo setting. You'll want to test that.